# Include Example Value of body instead of parameters, Django swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

Is there any way to include example value/schema to a django-rest-framework for functions/api_view

Example: https://generator3.swagger.io/index.html

[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3SB5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to edit generated JSON schema by yourself, check this topic for the render: [How to use custom YAML file as API documentation in Django REST Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296494/how-to-use-custom-yaml-file-as-api-documentation-in-django-rest-framework)